# Inserting TableRows into TableLayout programmatically - TextView inside TableRow won't display

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout, layoutparams

Okay, so I'm trying to insert `TableRows` into a `TableLayout` programmatically every time a button is tapped. Each of these rows contain a `TextView` set to some String. My problem is, that although the `TableRow` is inserted successfully, the text within the TextView that is itself inside the `TableRow` won't show up.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
    //prepare TextView to put inside a TableRow
    TextView text = new TextView(MyClass.this);
    text.setText(someString);
    text.setTextSize(15);
    text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9900"));
    text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


    //Prepare TableRow to be inserted
    TableRow row = new TableRow(MyClass.this);
    row.addView(text);
    row.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //add row to the table
    someTableLayout.addView(row);
```

The result:
A row is inserted, but I can't see the text (I know the row is inserted since I can see the dividers between each row). I'm guessing it has something to do with the `LayoutParams`? I'm probably overlooking something very stupid... but I have no idea...

Screenshot after I click `Roll` which should insert a row with the string/TextView:
[image]

The "Start By Rolling" TextView is the first row which I put in through the XML file. It displays fine, but the rows inserted programmatically don't

Comment: How your UI looks like ? Can you post screenshot of your current UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this is you have a `TextView` with height `match_parent` and a `tablerow` with height `wrap_content` so make `TextView` height to wrap_content as well.

And second assign appropriate LayoutParams for ex:

```
TextView text = new TextView(MyClass.this);
text.setText(someString);
text.setTextSize(15);
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9900"));
text.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


//Prepare TableRow to be inserted
TableRow row = new TableRow(MyClass.this);
row.addView(text);
row.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//add row to the table
someTableLayout.addView(row);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Also, why do we have to use the appropriate LayoutParams? Wouldn't just using `LayoutParams` directly work anyways?

Comment: Every layout param is different it defines the properties with respect to the parent layout. You can allways use ViewGroup.LayoutParams but if you want some specific properties to apply like weigth in linearlayout you should have appropriate layoutparam

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```